# Mixing POST request with websocket response - is it a bad practice?

Tags: node.js, sockets, post, express, socket.io

Here is a short snippet of node.js code (express.js and socket.io). Could sending POST requests and emitting socket responces be considered as a bad practice and why?E.g.:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.post('/tickets', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    io.emit('ticket', req.body);
    return res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: If you take the burden of setting up a socket communication (full duplex), which couples tightly the 2 parts, why should you send post requests through HTTP and return responses through socket?

Comment: Agreed with niconic here - though I can think of some cases in which you'd want a non-socket system to perform XHR post requests and then send a response to socket connections. I can't think of a reason other than potential confusion/muddling as to why it would be a bad practice - just make sure its the most coherent design for what you're trying to support.

Comment: You are emitting to everyone here, not just the client that send the request.

Comment: Yes I'm emiting to everyone and this is precisely my intension here (not using socket rooms in this particular case). About the burden mentioned by niconic: My idea is to submit native POST request without having to write a single line of js code for it - I fully understand that listening for the socket responce will require having socket event listener written in js

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with that. I actually created a notification system that receives the message and destination as a post and sends notifications to multiple sockets like that. 
From your code it looks like that's what your are doing, someone creates a ticket and you send a notification to all listeners.

That seems to be the most practical way and added bonus of being a proper api for use with external server like php or .net. If you're just using it from your own node app than perhaps you could just make it a socket event instead unless you are planning on getting requests from outside your app.